Why does removing `skip-grant-tables` cause resource conflict error for mysqld?
After hours of searching, I have managed to narrow a mysqld issue down to a point, which I cannot find reason for.
I am attempting to launch multiple instances of mysqld on my Ubuntu server. When running a single instance, my process is as follows:

Run mysqld with an options file containing skip-grant-tables
Use the mysql client to FLUSH PRIVILEGES; and allow root@localhost to access the server.
Kill the mysqld process
Remove the line skip-grant-tables from the options file
Relaunch mysqld when desired

This works without issue. When I attempt to launch a second instance of mysqld, the above steps work fine also - except I cannot include step (4).
If I include skip-grant-tables in my options file, mysqld launches without issue. If I remove skip-grant-tables, I get several errors:
2024-04-16T19:31:36.478828Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011292] [Server] Plugin mysqlx reported: 'Preparation of I/O interfaces failed, X Protocol won't be accessible'
2024-04-16T19:31:36.478932Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011300] [Server] Plugin mysqlx reported: 'Setup of bind-address: '*' port: 33060 failed, `bind()` failed with error: Address already in use (98). Do you already have another mysqld server running with Mysqlx ?'
2024-04-16T19:31:36.478966Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013597] [Server] Plugin mysqlx reported: 'Value '*' set to `Mysqlx_bind_address`, X Plugin can't bind to it. Skipping this value.
2024-04-16T19:31:36.479059Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011300] [Server] Plugin mysqlx reported: 'Setup of socket: '/tmp/mysqlx.sock' failed, another process with PID 419201 is using UNIX socket file'
2024-04-16T19:31:36.636815Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2024-04-16T19:31:36.636894Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2024-04-16T19:31:36.644131Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010262] [Server] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Address already in use
2024-04-16T19:31:36.644151Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010257] [Server] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2024-04-16T19:31:36.644169Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2024-04-16T19:31:38.237950Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /rootInstallDir/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown
2024-04-16T19:31:38.237978Z 0 [System] [MY-015016] [Server] MySQL Server - end.

I am using UNIX socket files, not ports, so I'm not sure why ports are being mentioned. Excluding log settings, my options file is:
[mysqld]
socket=/tmp/unique.sock
pid_file=/unique/path.pid
datadir=/unique/path

After many hours searching, advice, guidance or an explanation of what is causing this issue is greatly appreciated.
Update
After further testing, I am confident the error is due to the presence of skip-grant-tables as I execute the following steps:

Run mysqld with options file containing skip-grant-tables. mysqld runs successfully
I start a second instance with skip-grant-tables. mysqld runs successfully
I kill the second instance
I start a second instance without skip-grant-tables. mysqld exits soon after starting with the error detailed above.
I add skip-grant-tables to the options file and start a second instance. mysqld runs successfully.

Why will mysqld not start without skip-grant-tables ?

the error tells you that you didn't shut down the mysql server

How do you interpret a shutdown did not occur from the error messages above ?

the deafult port define in the ini/cnf file is 3306 but it triedand failed to bind it  Plugin mysqlx reported: 'Setup of bind-address: '*' port: 33060 failedsecond it tried to use pipes but it shows that another orocess is using it 'Setup of socket: '/tmp/mysqlx.sock' failed, another process with PID 419201  so chekc the processid, and you will see that is the mysqld that you didn't stop

Why is mysqld attempting to use a port ? I have set a definition for a socket in the options file, and if I run without skip-grant-tables, mysqld listens on the socket, not a port ?
The PID of my first mysqld instance is causing the issue - but only when skip-grant-tables is omitted from the options file.

it is the default settingm that it tries to open the port, but that is not the issue the pipes is alredy in sue by process PID 419201, so you must check what that is and why it is blocking

I will investigate the resource conflict - is the issue mysqld attempting to use a default port/socket when (a) I don't have this resource conflict issue if I add skip-grant-tables and (b) I set mysqld to use a unique socket file under [mysqld] in its options file ? What is the explanation for this ?
